# VMWare Error: Read-only file system during write on

Tags: vmware-esxi, filesystems, command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere, vmfs

I tried hundreds of forums and posts, but nothing seem to help!

I have vSphere ESXi 5.5. and when starting ESXi the first time it created and formatted a storage automatically.

For some reason I removed it and now I cannot get my disks/storage back! No problem if I need to reformat but even that is impossible !

I tried to reuse it, to format it, whatever possible, but nothing is working:

The only message I get is : Error: Read-only file system during write on /dev/disks/naa.(...) !

For example :

```
# partedUtil mklabel /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1 msdos
Error: Read-only file system during write on /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
WriteNewPtable: Unable to commit to device /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
partedUtil delete partition gives the same message.
```

partedUtil setptbl gives the same message.

fdisk (delete, new partitions, write) is of no use.

```
# partedUtil  getptbl /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
gpt
1215155 255 63 19521474560
1 63 8386622 EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7 linuxNative 0
2 8386623 13629502 9D27538040AD11DBBF97000C2911D1B8 vmkDiagnostic 0
```

Really, after trying more than 30 hours, I don't know anymore what to do ?

Any help would be very much appreciated...

Denis

P. S. ESXi 5.5.0
P. P. S. The message in the GUI is Appel "HostDatastoreSystem.CreateVmfsDatastore" pour l'objet "ha-datastoresystem" sur ESXi "172.16.1.244" a échoué

Comment: Is this local storage or is it over iSCSI/FC?

Comment: local RAID SATA or SAS disks

Comment: Is the host in a cluster?

Comment: host is not in a cluster. Finally I found 50% of the problem cause : coredump partition.

Comment: Is this the only disk in the server? If so, then that first partition might be the ESXi system area, which would make sense why it won't let you delete it

Comment: No there is another disk (USB stick) with VMware boot/system disk.

Comment: Have you booted into any other OS (live CD or something) to see if you can delete it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, thank to [communities.vmware.com](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2472738#2472738).

Maybe this solved only 50% of the cause of the problem, but at least access to the disk can be regained.

```
# esxcli system coredump partition get
Active: naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1:2
Configured: naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1:2
```

We see that this coredump partition is using our disk. This is what I did :

```
# esxcli system coredump partition set --enable false
# partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1 2
```

It's now a lot better :

```
# partedUtil getptbl /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
gpt
1215155 255 63 19521474560
1 63 8386622 EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7 linuxNative 0
```

But it's not 100% solved :

```
# partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1 1
Error: Read-only file system during write on /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
Unable to delete partition 1 from device /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
```

But then, by unactivating that partition, I was able to recreate a coredump partition on the disk from the GUI and then recreate a storage.

Now, this is not clean as initially (some small holes and strangely coredump at the end) but I would say the problem is solved:

```
# partedUtil getptbl /dev/disks/naa.600605b009a647b01c5ed73926b7ede1
gpt
1215155 255 63 19521474560
1 63 8386622 EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7 linuxNative 0
3 8388608 19521267711 AA31E02A400F11DB9590000C2911D1B8 vmfs 0
2 19521267712 19521472511 9D27538040AD11DBBF97000C2911D1B8 vmkDiagnostic 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked but I also had to relocate the syslog file on the host from `/scratch/log` to `/tmp` before I could delete the partition. Once the partition was deleted and the datastore created I relocated the syslog file to the original location, `/scratch/log`. This was on a ESXI 6.5 host.